# IMapBuilder Wordpress Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, wordpress

I'm developing a new map in the IMapBuilder plugin [1], but I've problems with it. I think it's more a JSON problem, I'll explain it:

I want to extract a JSON array from a.json, that is like this:

```
[
{"...":"...",
...},
{"...":"...",
...}
]
```

Now, if I go to the Chrome console and enter:

```
var json_array = $.getJSON('a.json'); [ENTER]

var real_array = eval(json_array.responseText); [ENTER]
```

I get all the objects in the real_array. The problem comes when all is toghether. When I put it in the JavaScript code, it says me that it's undefined. I've searched about it and all people say that it's about synchronization, but if I put it synchronized, it says me that it cannot be like that because the thread can't stop because it would be worse for the users. So, I don't know if it's all clear.

Thank you in advance.

[1] http://codecanyon.net/item/interactive-map-builder-for-wordpress/7229358?ref=meisterpixel

Comment: you have to consume the data in complete callback of `$.getJSON`. See docs

Comment: I've tried putting something like this:
    $.getJSON('a.json', function(data) {
        real_array = data;
    });
And it doesn't work neither

Comment: you have to use that array in the callback, ajax is asynchronous. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call